# Get the 'name' of a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine original name of variable after its passed to a function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404057/determine-original-name-of-variable-after-its-passed-to-a-function)

I would like to know if its possible to get the actual name of a variable.

For example:

```
var foo = 'bar';
function getName(myvar) {  
  //some code
  return "foo"  
};
```

So for getName(foo) will return "foo"

Is that possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: why would you be interested in variable name? Rather your logic in functions should depend on variable values right?

Comment: I find this code extremely weird. I wonder what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Never seen it done, why would you need it anyway? You already know it. It sounds like you should restructure your scripts to remove this neccessity.

Comment: Luckily this isn't possible in JavaScript, otherwise you'd end up with something horrible³ like this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749796/how-to-get-the-original-variable-name-of-variable-passed-to-a-function/2749857#2749857

Comment: Also a duplicate of the 2009 [How to convert variable name to string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417645/how-to-convert-variable-name-to-string-in-javascript)

Comment: This is pretty useful feature if you trying build a debugger or auto register a namespace without redeclaring or declaring another variable. I see some extremely useful cases for this.

Comment: See `nameof` operator in C# for use case. [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. When you call a function you pass an object, not a variable. The function doesn't care where the object came from.

You can go the other way though if you call your function as follows:

```
getName('foo')
```

Or pass both the value and the name:

```
getName(foo, 'foo')
```

Comment: Just a comment, why would I pass a harcoded string value 'foo' when I know I am going to get it as return value?

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag: How exactly will you get it as a return value if you don't pass it in as a parameter? You're assuming that what the OP is asking is possible. Perhaps it is... but I'd *really* like to see some evidence of that please.

Comment: I totally agree with you. This is one of the possible ways to getting what is required, but from programming perspective, if I am using that return value for further operations, I already know that value before passing it to function and need not wait for the return value. No offence, but I am actually assuming getting variable name is not posisble since it does not help in programming.

Comment: I know it's way old, but for future reference... It does help in programming, in some very speficic features, it's actually possible in c# using the nameof operator (wrong results if used for arguments as the OP wanted, but I believe he wouldn't need a function). I came to this exactly with a need. Think about it when you have a process to change other process parameters and you want the other process to react to some specific parameters changes. Would be very fragile to do something like `if (argumentName == 'myArgument')` because the name could change. Rather `== nameof(myArgument)`

Comment: This could be useful for refactoring during debugging..

Comment: You can write function `getName(variable){ return Objects.keys(variable)[0]}` and call it this way `var abc = "xyz"; console.log(getName({abc}));`