# Angularjs getting variable name with highest value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several variables with some values assigned. For ex:

Gain_weight = 0.01
Gain_weather = 0.02

and some more like this. Now I want to get the variable name with highest value assigned.

When I do something like this It returns the value not the name.

```
var rootNode = Math.max(Gain_weight,Gain_smoking,Gain_exercising,Gain_foodhabits,Gain_parent_heartattack,
            Gain_alcohol,Gain_occupation,Gain_workinghrs);
```

So instead of value how can I get the highest value assigned string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376295/getting-key-with-the-highest-value-from-object

Comment: Why do you need this, what is the use case? It isn't possible to programmatically obtain a variable name in the manner you suggest here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565031/get-the-name-of-a-variable-in-javascript) it seems it may not be possible to get the name.

A way around can be either using an `object` or a associate array with name as same of variable name and it's value as the variable value

Hope this snippet will help to understand

```
// Array with name value pair
var _myDemoArray = [
{name:'Gain_weight',
 value:0.01},
{name:'Gain_weather',
value:0.02}]

 // sort the array in descending order to get the element with maximum value. 
var _getSortedElem = _myDemoArray.sort(function(a,b){
  return b.value -a.value;
});
// The first element of this sorted array will have element with maximum value
console.log(_getSortedElem[0].name);
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/uxjuau99/) for demo