# Variable name as a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get a variable name as a string in Javascript? (like [`NSStringFromSelector`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395257-nsstringfromselector) in [Cocoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)))

I would like to do like this:

```
var myFirstName = 'John';
alert(variablesName(myFirstName) + ":" + myFirstName);

--> myFirstName:John
```

---

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to connect a browser and another program using JavaScript. I would like to send instance names from a browser to another program for callback method:

```
FooClass = function(){};
FooClass.someMethod = function(json) {
  // Do something
}

instanceA = new FooClass();
instanceB = new FooClass();
doSomethingInAnotherProcess(instanceB); // result will be substituted by using instanceB.someMethod();

...
```

From another program:

```
evaluateJavascriptInBrowser("(instanceName).someMethod("resultA");");
```

In PHP:
[How to get a variable name as a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php/255335#255335)

Comment: @delnan Indeed, +1. I can't think of another way to put it than "if you can write `variablesName(myFirstName)`, you already know the variable name." I'm trying, but I can't...

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417645/how-to-convert-variable-name-to-string-in-javascript

Comment: maybe for that you could store in a variable and later convert it to json for example {"instanceA": instanceA} and send it to the server using ajax or get/post call and that you can process in php and get name of the instance...

Comment: @deceze, sure, you know the name, but that doesn't mean you can/want to type it in manually. Maybe you want to dump a bunch of variables for debugging purposes and don't feel like manually typing `console.log("myvar = " + myvar);` over and over again, for each variable.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Typically, you would use a hash table for a situation where you want to map a name to some value, and be able to retrieve both.

```js
var obj = { myFirstName: 'John' };
obj.foo = 'Another name';
for(key in obj)
    console.log(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: @htafoya:  Indirectly, yes - all properties of `obj` are printed as `name: value` pairs. But the explaining text could be more clear.

Comment: @Mat I understand the code, but generally the OP question is used for something more complex as dynamic assignations where you can select the variable from a generated string. Or where simply creating a dictionary to print a value is overkill.

Comment: @htafoya - yes, something simple like nameof(varname) in C#.

Comment: I think the only reason this "doesn't answer the question" is because it doesn't start with "You cannot get the name of the constant or a variable in JavaScript. The closest thing to what you want...", like this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37393679

Answer (score 205):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
const myFirstName = 'John'
Object.keys({myFirstName})[0]

// returns "myFirstName"
```

Comment: This answer is similar to [@SethWhite's] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39669231/5876282) but much simplified. Thanks!

@bluejayke I think this answer comes years later after the original accepted answer. But yes, currently this is the best - except maybe the "pop()" usage suggested [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54345153/5876282)

Comment: is it possible to make function that will accept variable and print it's name? I've tried wrap your code inside a function but id returned me name which was used as argument

Comment: @WakanTanka If yo create a proper question, I'll answer it there.

Comment: @WakanTanka no, that would not work. As you discovered, it will just print the name you give the function argument. I think it helps to see how such a function would compile to an older Javascript spec. You can see in this example (https://jsfiddle.net/bigpopakap/wq891ghr/2/) that the {variable} syntax is just short for {variable: variable}, so it is impossible to use the variable name from the calling function

Comment: Beware: this will not work if you use auto-refactoring in VS Code to rename `myFirstName` variable to `myLastName`, for example. It will do this: `Object.keys({ myFirstName: myLastName })[0];`

Answer (score 170):

Like Seth's answer, but uses `Object.keys()` instead:

```js
const varToString = varObj => Object.keys(varObj)[0]

const someVar = 42
const displayName = varToString({ someVar })
console.log(displayName)
```

Comment: @titusfx you can swap out const for let or var and it works just the same. But if you're using a transpiler for the object destructuring in the first place, it probably supports const already.

Comment: This seems to depend on using ES6?

Comment: @O'Rooney Yes, it is ES6 specific.

Comment: Excelent idea. With that, we can create a funcion capable of settiing multiple outputs by value, reading from terminal arguments: `const getArgs = (varObj:any) => { const keys = Object.keys(varObj); process.argv.slice(2).forEach((arg, i) => varObj[keys[i]] = arg); return varObj; }`

Answer (score 58):

In ES6, you could write something like:

```js
let myVar = 'something';
let nameObject = {myVar};
let getVarNameFromObject = (nameObject) => {
  for(let varName in nameObject) {
    return varName;
  }
}
let varName = getVarNameFromObject(nameObject);

console.log(varName);
```

Not really the best looking thing, but it gets the job done.

This leverages ES6's object destructuring.

More info here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/

Comment: Great answer!! This particular use of object destructing is new to me (line 2 `let nameObject = {myVar}` so useful! It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Got any links?

Comment: @LaurenceLord it's called property shorthand. Assigning an object property without a definition (something: 'asdf'), will cause JS to define the property with the name of the variable and its value {something} === {something:something}. https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand

Comment: @LaurenceLord sidenote: it's "destruct**uring**" not "destruct**ing**" :) , although this in particular is not an "object" destructuring it's just the "Object Literal Property Value Shorthand" Seth mentioned. Object destructuring is a very specific term in JS referring to auto destructuring of objects like `...` or `var {a,b} = {a: "cool", b: "hot"}` etc.

Comment: MDN link to the "Shorthand property names" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015

Comment: You mean !
const getVarNameFromObject = (nameObject) => {
  return Object.keys(nameObject)[0];
};

Answer (score 50):

Get a string from any valid Javascript (variable, class):

```
const nameOf = (f) => (f).toString().replace(/[ |\(\)=>]/g,'');
```

Examples:

```
nameOf(() => myVariable)             // myVariable
nameOf(() => myVariable.name)        // myVariable.name
nameOf(() => myVariable.name.length) // myVariable.name.length
nameOf(() => myVariable.name[10])    // myVariable.name[10]
nameOf(() => MySuperClass)           // MySuperClass
```

Comment: This is the only answer out of the numerous answers here that worked for me as My 'object' was replicating a C# enum eg: `var myEnum = {A:1, B:5, C:27}

Comment: Could you update your answer and create a `function`. I do not know how to use your code.

Comment: @Radek `const nameOf = function (f) { return (f).toString().replace(/[ |\(\)=>]/g,''); };`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: This is genius!

Comment: I'd recommend using `const nameOf = (f) => (f).toString().replace(/(\(\) => )/g,'');`. Then it's easy to modify, such as if you want to change "this.var" to "var", you can just do `const nameOf = (f) => (f).toString().replace(/(\(\) => this\.)/g,'');`

Comment: Now that should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 26):

Probably pop would be better than indexing with [0], for safety (variable might be null).

```js
const myFirstName = 'John'
const variableName = Object.keys({myFirstName}).pop();
console.log(`Variable ${variableName} with value '${myFirstName}'`);

// returns "Variable myFirstName with value 'John'"
```

Comment: If myFirstName is passed to a function (containing this code) as argument v, then variableName is reported as v instead of myFirstName.

Comment: Of course, when you do `const x = 'John'` and `const y = x`, `y` will just store a copy of the value. If instead the value was an object, `y` would just point at the object's reference. There can be multiple variable assignments to a value but there is no such thing as an "original" assignment not anything of that kind is stored anywhere, so it's impossible to know.
You could wrap it, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61779045/1931117).

Comment: Even if `myFirstName == null`, `Object.keys({myFirstName})[0]` would still return `'myFirstName'`, no?

Answer (score 20):

```
var x = 2;
for(o in window){ 
   if(window[o] === x){
      alert(o);
   }
}
```

However, I think you should do like "karim79"

Comment: This will only work at window scope (breaks when inside a function).

Comment: Agreed - but its the closest to answering the OP's question. Gj.

Comment: also if you are testing a primitive, it will alert all the variables that have the same value, or if two variables have the same object assigned to them. For example if the first line was `x = 2; y = 2;` or `x = {a:1}; b = x;` it would alert each of them

Comment: If you want this to work in a **function scope** you can try using the function name instead of window, like:
 `var foo = function f(){ f.x = 2; for(o in f){ if(f[o]===f.x) alert(o); } }` then calling `f()` will alert 'x'

Comment: @aljgom - good point. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64ykoj73/) to try it out.

Comment: This fails for:
function outer()
 {
 var a={b:"c"};
 alert(foo(a));
 }

Comment: Fails for:
var a={b:"c"};
alert(name(a.b));

function name(v)
 {
 for(o in window){ 
   if(window[o] === v){
      return o;
   }
}
}

Answer (score 19):

This works for basic expressions

```
const nameof = exp => exp.toString().match(/[.](\w+)/)[1];
```

Example

```
nameof(() => options.displaySize);
```

Snippet:

```js
var nameof = function (exp) { return exp.toString().match(/[.](\w+)/)[1]; };
var myFirstName = 'Chuck';
var varname = nameof(function () { return window.myFirstName; });
console.log(varname);
```

Comment: This actually works pretty well! the only problem is when you pass in something like this:
nameof(() => options.subOptions.displaySize) which returns "subOptions"
Instead, I used this regex: exp.toString().match(/(?=[^.]*$)(\w+)/g)[0]

Comment: I get undefined from:
var a={b:"c"};
alert(name(a));
function name(exp)
 {
 exp.toString().match(/(?=[^.]*$)(\w+)/g)[0];
 } // name

Answer (score 13):

```
var somefancyvariable = "fancy";
Object.keys({somefancyvariable})[0];
```

<s>This isn't able to be made into a function as it returns the name of the function's variable.</s>

```
// THIS DOESN'T WORK
function getVarName(v) {
    return Object.keys({v})[0];
}
// Returns "v"
```

Edit: Thanks to [@Madeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8868419/madeo) for [pointing out how to make this into a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript/46577990#comment101632234_46577990).

```
function debugVar(varObj) {
    var varName = Object.keys(varObj)[0];
    console.log("Var \"" + varName + "\" has a value of \"" + varObj[varName] + "\"");
}
```

You will need call the function with a single element array containing the variable. `debugVar({somefancyvariable});`
Edit: `Object.keys` can be referenced as just `keys` in every browser I tested it in but according to the comments it doesn't work everywhere.

Comment: Error: "Can't find variable keys"

Comment: keys is not defined

Comment: it should be like this 
`const getVarName = (v) => Object.keys(v)[0];`
and then call the function like this `getVarName({whatEverVariable})`

Answer (score 12):

Shortest way I have found so far to get the variables name as a string:

```js
const name = obj => Object.keys(obj)[0];

const whatsMyName = "Snoop Doggy Dogg";

console.log( "Variable name is: " + name({ whatsMyName }) );
//result: Variable name is: whatsMyName
```

Answer (score 7):

best way using Object.keys();

example : for getting multi variables names in global scope

```js
// multi variables for testing
var x = 5 , b = true , m = 6 , v = "str";

// pass all variables you want in object
function getVarsNames(v = {}){
  // getting keys or names !
  let names = Object.keys(v);
  // return array contain all names of variables 
  return names;
}

// testing if that work or not 
let VarsNames = getVarsNames({x , b , m , v});

console.log(VarsNames); // output is array [x , b , m , v]
```

Answer (score 6):

Since **ECMAScript 5.1** you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the names of all properties from an object.

Here is an example:

```js
// Get John’s properties (firstName, lastName)
var john = {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'};
var properties = Object.keys(john);

// Show John’s properties
var message = 'John’s properties are: ' + properties.join(', ');
document.write(message);
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who would like to print variableName and variableValue for debugging purposes, here is a function:

```
const printNameValue = (v)=> {
  var varName = (v).toString().replace(/[ |\(\)=>]/g, '')
  var varValue = (v)()
  // neat : console.log(varName,varValue);
  // with some coloring  : 
  console.log("\033[1;96m[\033[1;33m " + varName + " :\033[0;0m " + varValue+"\033[1;96m ]\033[0;0m");
}
```

Example:

`const myNiceVariable = 1234`
call:
`printNameValue(()=> myNiceVariable )`
result:
[image: display with colors in the terminal]

Answer (score 3):

This worked using Internet Explorer (9, 10 and 11), Google Chrome 5:

```js
   
var myFirstName = "Danilo";
var varName = Object.keys({myFirstName:0})[0];
console.log(varName);
```

Browser compatibility table:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Google Chrome 5? really??

Comment: @avalanche1, according to MDN version compatibility table.

Answer (score 2):

You can reflect on types in [javascript](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/28/Simple-JavaScript-Object-Reflection-API-%28NET-Style%29.aspx) and get the name of properties and methods but what you need is sth like *`Lambda Expressions Trees`* in .NET, I think it's not be possible due to dynamic nature and lack of static type system in javascript.

Comment: I don't think JS falls short of lambdas or related tools of functional programming.

Comment: But I think there is no structure equivalent to Expression Trees in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

I needed this, don't want to use objects, and came up with the following solution, turning the question around.

**Instead of converting the variable name into a string, I convert a string into a variable.**

This only works if the variable name is known of course.

Take this:

```
var height = 120;
testAlert(height);
```

This should display:

```
height: 120
```

This can be done like this:

```
function testAlert(ta)
{
    a = window[ta];
    alert(ta + ': ' + a); 
}

var height = 120;
testAlert("height");
// displays: height: 120
```

So I use the string `"height"` and turn that into a variable `height` using the `window[]` command.

Comment: In your second case, height is a property of the `window` object because the variable of the same name was declared at window scope. This works *only* if the variable is declared at window scope, not in a function/closure.

Answer (score 1):

When having a function write a function that changes different global variables values it is not always myfirstname it is whatever happens to be passing through. Try this worked for me.

**<sub>Run in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rp6m9gz/)</sub>**

```js
var jack = 'jill';
function window_getVarName(what)
{
  for (var name in window)
  {
    if (window[name]==what)
    return(name);
  }
  return("");
}
document.write(window_getVarName(jack));
```

Will write to the window 'jack'.

Comment: This is not reliable. There could be any number of variables on the window object with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this function based on JSON as someone suggested, works fine for my debug needs

```js
function debugVar(varNames){
let strX = "";
function replacer(key, value){
    if (value === undefined){return "undef"}
    return value
    }    
for (let arg of arguments){
let lastChar;
    if (typeof arg!== "string"){
        let _arg = JSON.stringify(arg, replacer);
        _arg = _arg.replace('{',"");
        _arg = _arg.replace('}',"");            
        _arg = _arg.replace(/:/g,"=");
        _arg = _arg.replace(/"/g,"");
        strX+=_arg;
    }else{
    strX+=arg;
    lastChar = arg[arg.length-1];
    }
    if (arg!==arguments[arguments.length-1]&&lastChar!==":"){strX+=" "};
}
console.log(strX)    
}
let a = 42, b = 3, c;
debugVar("Begin:",{a,b,c},"end")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for something quick and dirty, this might work:

```
var zox = 150;

cl("zox");

function cl(c) {
    console.log(c + ': ' + this[c]); // zox: 150    
}
```

Comment: That's not obtaining the variable name from the variable itself. It needs to know the variable name in advance.

Answer (score -4):

No, there is not.
Besides, if you can write `variablesName(myFirstName)`, you already know the variable name ("myFirstName").

Comment: Not necessarily true if the code is being minified ;)

Comment: Also the point of using e.g. `nameof(myVariable)` in C# (which returns a string "myVariable" is to shield against mistakes when refactoring or making other changes to the code. A common use case is to add the variable's name to an error message being thrown. For the most parts I consider string literals a code smell, and suspect that is why at least Visual Studio, shows them in a red/orange color. I know I know, this question is about Javascript, but I just explained why I ended here.

Comment: var test = 1235125142;
console.log(Object.keys({test}).pop()) // "test"

Comment: @bluejayke Call me ignorant, but after 8 years I still fail to see how that's any better than `console.log('test')` or when you'd really need it.