# Get name of variable

Tags: javascript, html

In this code :

```
function myType(string){
    this.string = string;
    this.getName = function(){
        //return this.name;
    }
}
var myVar = new myType("string");
```

If I use `myVar.getName()`, it should return `myVar`. I need it to create a pop-up box that changes the whole `<body>` of the page, so it is important for me to get this function.

How can I  do so?

---

Edit :

What I'm trying to do is to write a custom object. This is the steps :

1. The user creates a object with a string;
2. I define the functions :
   (1) call() : It calls the inline pop-up box, which changes the whole body part of the page to the pop-up box; It saves the current body in `this.document_content`.
   (2) hide() : It change the body to `this.document_content` using `document.body.innerHTML`.
3. The user call by using `[Variable Name].call();"
4. The user can close the pop-up box by clicking a `<a>` button in it.

The problem that I found is in `2(1)`, which I cannot get the name of variable to put it in the code in `onclick`.

What can I do?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: You cannot determine, from inside the instance of the object, under which name it is referenced. keep in mind that it could be referenced under multiple names.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean......

Comment: yes, not possible in js.

Comment: Could you provide the real-life example? Because here, when calling `myVar.getName()`, you already know that `myVar`'s name is `myVar`, so I can't see the purpose of such a method...

Comment: Try the answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4602165/1977007

Comment: "*I cannot get the name of variable to put it in the code in onclick.*" That's the wrong way to do it anyway. Do not "create" code string for onclick attributes. Instead, assign a **handler function**, which does **reference** the current instance of your popup (by closure)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change your constructor you can do so -

```
function myType(name, string){
    this.string = string;
    this.name = name;
    this.getName = function(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
var myVar = new myType("myVar","string");
```

or you can create an hash:

```
function myType(name, string){
        this.string = string;
        this.name = name;
        this.getName = function(){
            return this.name;
        }
        var res = {}
        res[name] = this;
        return res;
    }
// Add response to an hash
var hash = {}
$.extend(hash, new myType("myVar","string"));
```

Comment: Yes, I've thought of that, but I am trying to make it more convenient.

Comment: see edit - another option