# How to get selector's variable on Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a selector is assigned to a variable, I need to get that variable name on `onclick`  I have created a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vmqqbrxb/) as an example

```
 var $main_img1 = $("<div/>").addClass('add1').appendTo($('#main_container'));
 var $main_img2 = $("<div/>").addClass('add2').appendTo($('#main_container'));

 $main_img1.click(function()
 {
     get_id()
 });

 $main_img2.click(function()
 {
      get_id()
 });
 function get_id(event)
 {
      console.log($(this))
      alert('i need to get selector variable on click')
 }
```

Output should be **$main_img1** and **$main_img2** when I click on the corresponding div

Comment: add the variable name as an attribute or id to the corresponding div and then u can get it by selecting the div attr

Comment: Any specific reason why do you want the variable name??

Comment: related: [Variable name as a string in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: My requirement is to get only to the variable name when assigned to any selector... Thats y i'm hanging

Comment: @PraJen any thoughts on my comment ??

Comment: I agree with iJay's approach, add it to an attribute on the new element somewhere. Important to note, though, id's must start with a letter, you can't assign the variable names in their entirety if they start with a $ character.

Comment: @ijay i should not use any custom attribute too..

Comment: There can be a thousand variables referring the same element, when an even occurs, You want to detect which *reference* was used to bind the handler..? I strongly believe this is an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which can be solved in a different manner.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vmqqbrxb/6/

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vmqqbrxb/7/

Comment: @Arun i satisfied with ur answer.. But it is like reassigning once again and getting the value in static manner.. can u help more simple like event.target.id alike.. so that i can get the value and split it

Comment: can anyone help pls..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, but not sure how you are going to use it

Used Array to get the variable name.

JS

```
    var arr = new Array();
    arr[0] = '$main_img1';
    arr[1] = '$main_img2';

    var $main_img1 = $("<div/>").addClass('add1 add').appendTo($('#main_container'));
    var $main_img2 = $("<div/>").addClass('add2 add').appendTo($('#main_container'));

      $main_img1.click(function()
                 {
                    get_id($(this))
                 });

       $main_img2.click(function()
                 {
                    get_id($(this))
                 });
    function get_id(event)
    {
        alert(arr[$('.add').index(event)]);
    }
```

**Update** : No array needed.

```
    function get_id(event)
    {
        ///var temp = '$main_img' + (parseInt($('.add').index(event)) + 1);
        var temp = '$main_img' + (parseInt($('#main_container > div').index(event)) + 1);
        alert(temp);
        console.log(eval(temp));
    }
```

[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/vmqqbrxb/8/)

Comment: I too know to acheive it many different way @karan.. but i want my question related answer... without using any additional array or etc..

Comment: Can u make as simple as event.target.id alike something.. beacuse i need to use this function for many variable.. and need to split the value from it too..

Comment: .addClass('add1 add') if u add another class my style wont be updated.. i'll be adding another class in dynamic..

Comment: Basically you will just need a relation in all `divs`. Instead of the `.add` you can add a class to their parent div. And use the parent div to get the index.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a workaround.. see if it helps you. Add a hidden element inside the corresponding divs and add the variable names as text to it. I slightly modified your method get_id() to get the variable name from your divs hidden element.

```
function get_id()
{
   console.log($(this))
   var selVar= $(this).parent().find('input:hidden:first').text(); 
   alert('selector variable' + selVar);
}
```

this will work for you.

Comment: i didnt get my output :(

Comment: Check this fiddle . This works fine. you need to add a hidden element and variable name to it. http://jsfiddle.net/khaleel/vmqqbrxb/14/

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe guessing from the class of the element you click on it and use reflexivity.

To know the element you click on it, just use `event.target` where `event` is a variable passed in the `click` function. Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmqqbrxb/5/) for an example.

The `get_id` method now looks like this:

```
function get_id(event) {
    console.log(event.target)
}
```

The value returned by `event.target` is the same as the value returned by the variable you declare it (`$main_img1` or `$main_img2`).

Comment: the variables $main_img1 and $main_img2, too. No?

Comment: Its just returning only the div element fully