# JavaScript: How to get name of the constant?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the name of constant :

```
const MY_CONSTANT = 1;
```

I want to show the name of my constant (MY_CONSTANT) not value (1).

Comment: You're going to have to explain the situation more thoroughly because it doesn't make sense as it is.

Comment: If you know the constant's name, can't you just print it ? `alert("MY_CONSTANT");`

Comment: How you suppose to target that constant?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Just use `if someValue === MY_CONSTANT then print("MY_CONSTANT")` This is pseudocode.

Comment: `const MY_CONSTANT = { name: "MY_CONSTANT", value: 1 }; console.log(MY_CONSTANT.name);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot get the name of the constant or a variable in JavaScript. The closest thing to what you want to do would be setting a property inside an object. Then, you can get the names of all keys.

```
var obj = { myFirstName: 'John' };
obj.foo = 'Another name';
for(key in obj)
    alert(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
```

See karim79's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)