# How to find the execution context object name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, executioncontext

I have below code trying to display the context from where checkObj() is invoked. 
For example, I need to see the output as 'a' since checkObj is invoked as a.checkObj().
Currently, only the type of 'this' is displayed i.e., Object{}

```
function checkObj(){
console.log(this);
}

var a = {checkObj:checkObj};
a.checkObj();
```

Comment: Objects don't have names; variables do. Objects are not necessarily stored in variables (or just one variable, for that matter).

Comment: If you want to log the variable name, `a`? That won't be possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the object variable name in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870307/getting-the-object-variable-name-in-javascript)

Comment: @melpomene So, the only way to find out where the checkObj() is invoked from is by referring the call-stack through debugger tool in browser?

Comment: This is not possibly , But you can set a string representation for this object using `toString` method then this is can be useful.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: @sabithpocker So, the only way to find out where the checkObj() is invoked from is by referring the call-stack through debugger tool in browser?

Comment: If you already have a reference to what you are checking against, you can do `myObj === this`. If you explain what you are actually trying to do and why, may be there is a different way of doing it.

Comment: @sabithpocker There is a function declaration of checkObj() in a messy code, and I'm just trying to figure out where it is invoked from and how?

Comment: Your best bet is debugger.

Comment: You should just put a debugger; statement inside the code and check if the function is called. There is an another function non standard property .caller.name https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller (never ever use this in production!!) which can be useful only for this nested function calls.