# How to return name of the new javascript declared object

Tags: javascript, object, variables

I want to retrieve the variable name that I just created without passing it as an argument.

Eg:

```
  Var ObjName = function(hello) {

  ...

  }

  Var something = new ObjName(66)
```

How do I get the new variable to return it’s own declared name? Eg: something.this.name returns “something”.

As a side note, I’m not looking for something.constructor.name. I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: `Var` will result in a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: It's not possible without some really weird hacks, but a script shouldn't depend on the names of its variables.

Comment: The var was autocorrected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the object variable name in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870307/getting-the-object-variable-name-in-javascript)

Comment: It’s close. But that method requires that I pass an argument to it. I wanted to kind of create a property in the object that would automatically store the created variable. Long story short I am developing a game engine with a scripting. But anytime a variable or object is created I need to know the name so I can make a save game file with all the data.

Comment: You never need or want unknown variable names. Please use an object instead: `const obj = {something: new ObjName(66)};` … `console.log(obj.something);`, or an array. As for _“I wanted to kind of create a property in the object that would automatically store the created variable”_, the answer already includes _“This is not possible in JavaScript.”_

Answer (score -1):

the following code prints the variable name:

```
var something = 'diego'
Object.keys({something})[0] // prints "something
```

Comment: So does `"something"`. You have to know the variable name in advance for this to work.