# How do I know who has instantiated a function?

Tags: javascript

```
const finder = new FinderClass();    
const gallery1 = new GalleryClass(finder);
const gallery2 = new GalleryClass(finder);
```

There is a "search" method on `finder`: `finder.search(query)`. When I call "search" how do I know whether the caller is `gallery1` or `gallery2`?

```
var GalleryClass = function(finder) {
    this._finder = finder;
}

GalleryClass.prototype = {
    doSearch(query) {
        return this._finder.search(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show how your classes looks like. And what happens to argument(`finder`) passed to `GalleryClass`

Comment: It's better if you reconsider your application design: there is almost never a good reason to find a caller unless you're implementing a tracing/debuggin/or alike tool.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870307/getting-the-object-variable-name-in-javascript