# Use Variable as its name and not its content

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes 2 inputs, the variable name as a string and the variable itself - it prints both via console.

```js
var variable1 = ["entry1","entry2"];
   function logthis(input1, input2){
    console.log(input1+ "\n " + input2)
    }
    
    logthis("variable1", variable1) ;
```

**I want to be able to use it as `logthis(variable1);` and get the same result.**

How can I reference the variable name (as a string) and not its contents?

eg, console.log(input2.name) will not work

Something like the C+ equivalent of "**nameOf**(*variable1*)"

Comment: Have you tried `logthis('variable1', variable1) ;`?

Comment: Your input is an array, not an object which have `name` property

Comment: @Satpal 2 - yes i know.I just want to type the variable name once.

Comment: @Durga - the input could potentially be any type,

Comment: check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript), it may help

Answer (score 1):

```js
var variable1 = ["entry1","entry2"];
function logthis(input1, input2){
  console.log(input1+ "\n " + input2)
}
    
logthis('variable1', variable1) ;
```

You are sending the reference. Pass first argument as string.

Comment: I want to be able to use it as logthis(variable1);

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your input from the table first

```js
function logthis(inputTable){
       var input1 = inputTable[0];
       var input2 = inputTable[1];

       console.log(input1+ "\n " + input2) // will display "entry1 \n entry2 "
    }
        
    var table1 = ["entry1","entry2"];
    logthis(table1);
```