# How to Get a Variable's Name (NOT VALUE) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to get a variable's name from code in javascript.

Ex:

```
var MYVAR = 3;//this is in file a.txt
abc(MYVAR);//this is in file a.txt

function abc(label) {//this is in file b.txt
    alert(label); // this will print 3, but i want to print the name of the variable i.e., MYVAR
}
```

Required OUTPUT: "MYVAR"
File a.txt cannot be changed, only file b.txt can be changed

- anyone know this?.. is it possible in the current spec of the
  language???

Comment: Quite impossible.

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: Checkout this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: window[<some_variable_name>] is throwing error. It will not work

Comment: No, it is not possible in any sane way. Why do you need this? The only sane reason to ever need this is for debugging, and there you're better off using a proper debugger, setting a breakpoint, and inspecting the stack trace.

Comment: Its not for debugging, Its required to add another customised feature to customer

Comment: Variable names are nothing you should base business logic on. Variable names can change and be refactored as the local code requires. Variables are placeholders in an algorithm, they do not carry business logic meaning. Variable names may be mangled when compiled and/or minified. **Do not try to depend on variables names in external code.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DIY solution for your problem.

You can cast your variable into an `object` and then use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the variable name in a string format.

---

```js
var MYVAR = 3;
abc({MYVAR});

function abc(label) {
  if (typeof label === 'object') {
    alert(Object.keys(label)[0]); // Alerts variable name
  } else {
    alert(label); // Alerts variable value
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually 

var MYVAR = 3;
abc(MYVAR); 
These are in 1 file.

Below code is in another file

function abc(label) {
    alert(label); // this will print 3, but i want to print the name of the variable i.e., MYVAR
}

I can change only this code. But not the 1st file code

Comment: What do you mean OP? @ShreelakshmiG

Comment: OP?? I didn't get U @Alex

Comment: _OP??_ OP = Oiginal Poster.. in that case it is you! @ShreelakshmiG

Comment: @ShreelakshmiG this is the closest you can get to. You will still have to wrap your variable in curly braces `{}` when you're passing the variable into your function. If you don't wrap it, it will output the value instead.

Comment: As you can see the question I have explained just in a more clear way. Both are in different files and the file where we call the function is not editable. We can make changes in the function definition only.

Comment: That's pretty much the most you can do. If you don't have control over the first file, then you can't use this function. Can you edit the code where you're invokin `abc()` ?

Comment: No, I can't edit the code of  invoking the function abc(). Is it possible to convert the variable MYVAR to object in function definition so that we can get the name and value??

Comment: It will not work as the variable you pass into your function is passed by reference, meaning that you can only access the value.

Comment: Oh. Okay. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @ShreelakshmiG no problem! :) Let's hope you find something.