# Look up variable name of a boolean in javascript

Tags: javascript

In js we can look up the name of a function

```js
var func1 = function() {}
console.log(func1.name) //prints func1
```

Can i do the same thing for a boolean?

```js
var myMightyBoolean = true
console.log(myMightyBoolean.name) //prints myMightyBoolean, this doesnt work thus the question
```

Edit: The following allows for it but only under certain conditions, watch comments below or top answer for more

console.log(Object.keys({myMightyBoolean}).pop())

Comment: possible duplicate, but didn't find it

Comment: The Function object has a name because it is provided by [Function.prototype.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Comment: @MaheerAli `Object.keys({myMightyBoolean}).pop()`

Comment: You can do this using ES6 as per the answer in the question linked above https://stackoverflow.com/a/39669231/206614

Comment: @JamesCoyle Yes but it doesn't make any sense to me why not just log `'myMightyBoolean'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The name of a function is a feature of the function.

```js
const foo = function bar () {};
console.log(foo.name);
```

If you create an anonymous function, then it will get a name from the variable you assign it to at the time of creation.

```js
const foo = function () {};
console.log(foo.name);
```

But only at the time of creation:

```js
function makeFunction() {
    return function () {};
}

const foo = makeFunction();
console.log(foo.name);
```

---

Boolean primitives aren't functions, they don't have names.

Given a set of variables or object properties, you could test each one in turn to find a match for the value of the boolean and then output the name of the variable/property … but that's not the same thing.