# Javascript get short circuit variable name

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting

I am checking for `null` like this:

let's say `c` is null.

```
if (a == null || b == null || c == null || d == null) { //short cirtcuit on the first null value (c)

    let grabNullKey = a == null || b == null || c == null || d == null;

    // I want this to grab the variable that is null, instead this logs `true`

    console.log(grabNullKey)
```

I want to log the variable name (`c`) to the user, is there a shorthand to output the variable name instead of doing 4 if statements?

Comment: Why are you trying to log the variable's name?

Comment: @adiga yes output `c` variable name, updated in question

Comment: But, why do you need this? I mean, it's possible to do this using a chain of if-else or using short hand property names.

Comment: @adiga Yeah, so I know I can do a big block of if-else statement (or switch statement) to `console.log` the variable name. But if the condition to check is very long it will require a very big block of if-else's, and since we are already short-circuiting on the variable that is null, I was hoping there is a quick way to output the variable name to the logs. It will be useful to log this info so when the condition breaks it's a lot quicker to debug.

Comment: It sounds like you want an array or an object with properties, rather than variables.

Comment: @honeybadger_execute if you resolve an identifier to a value, JS doesn't keep a reference to what the identifier was. If you do `something = foo || bar` you'd get the first non-falsey *contents* of a variable but cannot then reverse it to see where it came from. Unless you write an if-else chain or otherwise manually link the two.

Comment: Something like `const obj = { a, b, c, d };

const key = Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k] === null)` should work.

Comment: what do you want to do later with the variable name?

Comment: @NinaScholz log it, so it'll be easier to debug when an error occured later. Easier for other developers to troubleshoot

Comment: @adiga Will the `.find()` go through the variableObject sequentially? So in the order of (a -> b -> c -> d)

Comment: @honeybadger_execute yes (Guaranteed only in ES2015. You are already using `let`. So, it's fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the bad news, [JavaScript doesn't allow you to print a variable name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript). The good news is there is a way around it.

To be able to print the variable name, you are going to need to use an object instead of a series of variables. So you would need an object like this:

```
const variableObject = { a: true, b: true, c: null, d: true };
```

To find the first null value and print it, you would need to loop through they keys and find the first one that is null:

```
const variableObject = { a: true, b: true, c: null, d: true };
const variableNames = Object.keys(variableObject); // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
const firstNullVar = variableNames.find((key) => variablesObject[key] === null); // 'c'
console.log(firstNullVar); // will print the string 'c'
```

If none of the variables are `null`, this will print `undefined`, although getting around that is easy.

Comment: You can create an object using the existing variables like this: `const variableObject = { a, b, c, d }` [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: Will the `.find()` go through the `variableObject` sequentially? (`a` -> `b` -> `c` -> `d`)

Comment: As long as the key-value pairs are in that order in the object (e.g. `{ a: true, b: true, c: null, d: true }`), they keys do not evaluate to integers, and you are using ES2015, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Make an Object Literal and assign the variables as key/value pairs to the object. Pass the object as a parameter to the function demonstrated in the following demo:

#### function nulls(object)

```
function nulls(obj) {
  return (Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] === null)).join(', ');
}
```

**@params object [object]:**
Object Literal consists of key (variable names, `a`, `b`, `c`,...) and value (variable value , `1`, `2`, `null`,...)

- ***`Object.keys(object)`***  returns an array of keys (variable names)
- ***`.filter(key => object[key] === null)`*** returns an array of keys (variable names) that have the value (`object[key]`) of `null`
- ***`.join(', ')`*** returns the array of keys (variable names) as a string

```js
function nulls(obj) {
  return (Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] === null)).join(', ');
}

let x = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: null,
  d: 4,
  e: null,
  f: 6,
  g: null
};

console.log(nulls(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

think this could do it:

```
var itemsA = ['a','b','c','d'];
var valsA = [a,b,c,d];
var ind = valsA.indexOf(null);
if(ind != -1){
 console.log(itemsA[ind]); 
}
```

you can also do something similar by using a JSON object with find or findIndex