# How can i get object name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

How can i get object name in JAVASCRIPT

--

let smthng = {1,2,3}

console.log(smthng.toString(),smthng);

-> my expect : smthng {1,2,3}

Comment: `let smthng = {1,2,3}` is invalid syntax.

Comment: i was meant let smthng = [1,2,3]

Comment: easiest way to get a similar result is to do `console.log({smthng});`

Comment: By that point, why not just use `console.log('smthng')`?

Comment: I need to check object name on console.

Comment: hm, you're right, I guess it might be a little easier for debugging, to see what variable names hold which values ( rather than typing console.log('smthng', smthng) )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Objects in JavaScript do not intrinsically have names unless you create a property on your own that you consider to be its name. A variable initialized to an object literal is definitely **not** the "name" of the object; it's just a variable.

Comment: @Pointy

Thank you now i got 
i might rather attribute new property on object

Answer (score -1):

```
let smthng = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
console.log({ smthng: smthng }) // or console.log({ smthng }); should print {smthng:{a:1,b:2,c:3}}
```

Comment: sorry My desc was short

i was trying to catch variable name on console

so 

let smthng = [1,2,3]

i need my console to be printed as

//// smthng : [1,2,3] ////

one another example 

let another = [1,2,3]

i need my console to be printed as

//// another : [1,2,3]  ////

one another example

Comment: console.log({ smthng }) or console.log({ another }) will do what you want. Both will print {smthng:[1,2,3]} and {another:[1,2,3]}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.