# How to return reference object's name in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, reference

How can I obtain the name of the object I passed to a function, inside
 that function ?

```
var referencedObject = {
    someProperty : 'string'
};

var functionObject = {
    construct: function(reference){
        console.log(reference.toString());
    }
};

functionObject.construct(referencedObject);
```

I'm Looking for `referencedObject` as an output by the `console.log();`

Currently is giving me `[object object]`

Comment: I'm 99% confident you can't. That info is not available to the function at runtime.

Comment: You can't get the name of a variable, you would have to pass the name manually. Or alternatively - put the object in another object, and the name you desire to get as the key.

Comment: Taking a step back... Why do you need the *name* of the variable?  What's the overall goal here?

Comment: Not possible to implement generically. Unless you dynamically perform a reverse lookup by crawling the stacktrace using an AST parser. Which is...not easy, to say the least. Also, this is very likely [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain *why* you need this? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You can do it, but this question is a duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.
Those solutions do not return the objects name.
|||
So my options are:

* Passing the object and a string name
* Adding a name: property to the object
* Putting the object in another object

|||
I need this for a function that constructs HTML from a JS object that defines a 'layer', the objects name is required for the id tags of each div.
For clean workings i'm going for the third option, and putting all my layers in an object, so i can access each layers name as the key.
|||
Thank you all, you make this platform great !

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using '.toString()' method. Instead, you need JSON.stringify(your object). Therefore, your code should look something like this,

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(reference));
```

I hope that helps.