# React Native / Javascript - get name of imported module

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have imported a number of files containing components (each of them is a different vector shape)

There's one file per shape. Each file is called differently, eg: Circle.js, DarkStar.js, etc but each of them has a default export:

```
export default SvGElement;
```

All of them have exactly the same last line as above. I import all of them to another component using their aliases from filenames, eg:

```
import Circle from './Circle';
import DarkStar from './DarkStar';
```

I'm trying to render them all with descriptions. I'm fine with rendering them but I cannot access their names (eg. 'Circle', 'DarkStar', etc.)

`Circle.name` returns the 'SvgElement' string

`Circle.toString()` - returns the content of the component function

How would I go about capturing the name Circle, DarkStar to variables. I cannot change anything in the vector files (only in the file I'm importing them to)

Comment: I'm confused. You have a variable, and you want to know the name of the variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: You have to spell them out yourself, but you can cheat: `for (const [name, element] of Object.entries({Circle, DarkStar, …}))`

Comment: As they are react component try `Circle.displayName || Circle.name`, but maybe for functional component (and mnified prod bundle) you have to set it `Circle.displayName = "MyCircleComponent"` in Circle.js

Comment: Otherwise you cannot rely on file names or exported constant names as they can differ in optimized, uglified production build.