# get name of input variable (like Function.name)

Tags: javascript, reflection

I have a `Function` in which I want to retrieve the name of the variable that was used to call the function. How can I do that?

```
let fooVar = 3;
let barVar = "hello World";

function doStuff(variable) {
    let varName = ???; // retrieve name of variable
    return varName + ": " + variable;
}

document.write(doStuff(fooVar)); // should output "fooVar: 3"
document.write(doStuff(barVar)); // should output "barVar: hello World"
```

If `variable` was a `Function`, I could use `variable.name`.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52598270/5333340), but it will only return `"variable"`, not the name of the variable that was put into the function.

---

As an alternative: Is there a way to AUTOMATICALLY call a certain function whenever a variable is declared? If that was possible, I'd use the approach given in the link above to add the variable name to a map, then utilize that map inside the function to retrieve variable name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini no. I linked an answer to that question and explained why it does not help.

Comment: Yes true, it's impossible because you change name of variable into function so you must use object

Comment: It's not possible to do what you wanted

Comment: The other question is "Why do you want to do this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually impossible to do, as a workaround you can do something like this

```js
let fooVar = { name: 'fooVar', value: 3 };
let barVar = { name: 'barVar', value: 'Hello World' };

function doStuff({ name, value }) {
    let varName = name; // retrieve name of variable
    return varName + ": " + value;
}

console.log(doStuff(fooVar)); // should output "fooVar: 3"
console.log(doStuff(barVar));
```

or you can do

```js
let fooVar = 3;
let barVar = 'Hello World';

function doStuff(variable) {
    const arr = Object.entries(variable)[0];
    const [name, value] = arr;
    let varName = name; // retrieve name of variable
    return varName + ": " + value;
}

console.log(doStuff({ fooVar })); // should output "fooVar: 3"
console.log(doStuff({ barVar }));
```

Comment: Second workaround solves my problem, thanks!

Comment: No problem, please consider marking it as a correct answer if it helped :)