# How can I see if 2 specific string variables added

Tags: javascript, v8

How can I check if 2 variables with the same value are the same variable?

For example in the below code I created 2 variables with the same values and i pass:

```
function check_var(v){
  // Check if "v" (string) came from a or b
}

let a = "string";
let b = "string";

check_var(b);
```

I able to install v8 engine locally and change the the source code, but i am looking for more easy way to do it.

One way to do it is if I had a method in javascript that returns a unique value for each variable based on the variable name.

One more way to solve the problem is by logging all the javascript actions, by doing that i could see after the code executed if var a is the var that got into the `check_var` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: This isn’t possible from within JavaScript; you’d use reference types instead, e.g. objects or symbols. Are you actually trying to write a JS engine or transpiler or something similar? For what purpose are you trying to install V8 and change the source code? See [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/289905) and make sure your question doesn’t have it.

Comment: Perhaps look into parsing systems that already exist ie [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)? Here is your above snippet parsed: [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/068302f2b463cacbc96bd88744970f84/32410f001dda8793e671e649eb97585324ec4db6). If you click on the 'JSON' tab you'll see your call is parsed and the argument name identified.

Comment: No i just want to know if i can see the different between 2 variable with the same value using javascript @Sebastian Simon

Comment: The answer is "no" then. The value holds no reference to the variable it is assigned to. (also by the time you are dealing with `v` it is a new variable, neither `a` or `b`, so you would have to look at the call itself `check_var(b)`)

Comment: @eyal And again: _why_ do you think you need to know this?

Comment: I create my own dynamic xss scanner and i want to know if location.hash for example passed in the document.write function even if i do something like: let e = document.hash;document.write(e);

Comment: Then an AST is probably closest to this goal, e.g. ESTree. Still, this doesn’t sound robust at all. Why would the hash play a role in XSS? Why is the hash even there? If you’re worrying about XSS, this is probably the least of your concerns…

Comment: document.location.hash and document.write is just example of a place where attacker can send the xss payload and function that execute javascript it called DOM xss.

Comment: The AST is very nice for static analysis  however to check in runtime it doesnt help.

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot, JavaScript doesn't have a universal identity equality operator.

Strings, numbers and some other simple values can only be compared by value. Tho objects, including arrays are compared by identity.

```
const a = [1]
const b = [1]

a===b // false
```

If this is important you could box the value

```
const a = { value: 'string' }
const b = { value: 'string' }
const c = a

a.value === b.value // true
a === b // false
a === c // true
```