# Extension Typescript Class Property Methods

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to build something like below. I tried to find many places but did not get exactly what I wanted.

```
// Typescript Class or interface
export class(or interface) Person {
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
}
```

Now in the Angular component, I want to use something like this:

```
//Assume Person type is class
let p = new Persons();
```

then I want to achieve something like this when I write p.firstName.toPropertyName() to return the property's name. "firstName"
Here **toPropertyName()** is my extension method on any property of the object.

Again, I am aware of those object.keys that I can play with and achieve the above behavior, but that doesn't fit properly into my scenario.

In c# this can be achieved very easily using the reflection but having a hard time doing it in typescript/javascript.

Comment: No, that exact syntax is not possible. What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: For instance, look at the below code how the magical string is part of that form control name. 

<intput type="text" formControlName="firstName"/>

                                           vs

<intput type="text" [formControlName]="model.firstName.toPropertyName()"/>

Comment: Well I'd clearly prefer the more concise version. What do you hope to gain from the magic?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is not really something like a `nameof` in JavaScript. There are workaround though, see [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript) for more information.

---

I tried to come up with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type-safe approach, which doesn't automatically map a class property to a string but instead forces you to return the correct string with type checks. This has one big advantage: `toPropertyName()` returns a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the property name. Things like [`Object.keys({ variable })[0]`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwE4EsECMA2BTGBeGAIgBUBPAB2wGVhVzYUIZQRMBCQgbgChRJYk2CAFdMsAgHl0AK2zAoAOgDW2UhAAUAb3jI0WXAF8AlAG0ADAF0eAemsx7MAHoB+br3ARW2BZhABzdUERMSMeIA) only give you an arbitrary `string`.

On the other hand it's just sooo much code, quite hard to read and not very practical for real world cases. I used [`get`ters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#getters--setters) to modify the return value of a property.

```
type PropertyGetValue<V, T, K extends keyof T> = {
  value: V;
  toPropertyName: () => K;
};

class Extension<T> {
  protected getPropertyGetValue<V, K extends keyof T>(
    value: V,
    propertyKey: K,
  ): PropertyGetValue<V, T, K> {
    return { value, toPropertyName: () => propertyKey };
  }
}

class Person extends Extension<Person> {
  private _firstname: string;
  private _lastname: string;

  constructor(firstname: string, lastname: string) {
    super();

    this._firstname = firstname;
    this._lastname = lastname;
  }

  get firstname(): PropertyGetValue<
    typeof this._firstname,
    Person,
    "firstname"
  > {
    return super.getPropertyGetValue(this._firstname, "firstname");
  }

  set firstname(value: string) {
    this._firstname = value;
  }

  get lastname(): PropertyGetValue<typeof this._firstname, Person, "lastname"> {
    return super.getPropertyGetValue(this._lastname, "lastname");
  }

  set lastname(value: string) {
    this._firstname = value;
  }
}

const p = new Person("Jason", "Becker");

const firstname = p.firstname.value;
//    ^? const firstname: string
const firstnamePropertyName = p.firstname.toPropertyName();
//    ^? const firstnamePropertyName: "firstname"
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUBxCwBqBDANgVwgB5MAaKAFXIGkoIAPYCAOwBMBnKAawhAQDNKAPigBeKAG8AUFCgA3PIQBcUTAG4ZUYAnhIIKEADlsAWwgqAFAEoxI6hoC+GqQGNc2dpwCijFuwCWCMxEFCLSsmCITC5MrFAA5hi6yGgYOATEZFC0DExsnDx8gqEWmrIKGSpkZVCRegbUvCrUpJpWKsn6qViKmeRU2WE1cBj4cMyS8r3k2p0GxmaWNqIidSkgjSBQTpoOUnuu7p6w+uxBdL75UD55AUFEMKdBQxFw-gpMUAD6-P5w7MBmKZzFAAW9mPENK93thPl8joDgSowf4Ic5ZC4gmD8DEEHALL9-ojFqDgOD4uQEUCSSiITZwrJQfhkNZ0YzgAALfzsAB0Pz+AOp0HEhMFwKh7K5vPhHmJwqgVPFuykmkSwCgorl1g6iHW6B6GSINVAkAEWilfM1QtajJO-yCNsZACIrcCnZoXoyRsAxhN2Mz9Dy1XNuulCBZOdzLQK5eQXTGhU6rBKDrJ2BgNQngRYKspSeT6caLfyiUKxFMMimVbI1QrZULtbBdV0QPqw8QTRAzZHpa6zORHvbmHHFWYnZ7ZN7fUzkEGks2DG3ehHi6OICP627k8rNOn1Wuc71kWTUfFC7ae9HS8Dy7mIFWDpjmADauXmBAAO52s7MCxOgBSHhBE6cYAEIQC4PBwEmzhPi+fbymAPIITyd4aAA9OhtoAHoAPyuFi6oISGRg3uISEobMC6gAsECslImE4fhQA)

Comment: `p.firstname.value` is rather awkward to use. But it's the way to go if OP insists on writing `p.firstname.toPropertyName()`…

Comment: I agree, The whole thing is unhandy. However, I don't think there's a better way to to this, or is there?

Comment: I guess I would prefer a static function `propertyNameOf(p, "firstname")` (typed as `propertyNameOf<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(_: T, k: K): K { return k }`) or even just `propertyName<Person>("firstname")` to get the same type safety.

Comment: That's nice. The OP can decide which is the preferred syntax. `firstname.value` reminded  me of C# nullable types.