Convert some string value to array format
Can someone please help me to bring test value:
   let test = "a:1|b:2,3|c:4,5"

into below format:
   prod:[
         {
           name:test,
           product:{
                     a:[1],
                     b:[2,3],
                     c:[4,5]
                    }
          }]


What have you tried so far?

One solution could look like this:
Be careful with the regex, since I


const test = "a:1|b:2,3|c:4,5";
const regex = /(\w):([\d,]+)/gm;
const matches = test.matchAll(regex);
const prod = [];
const product = {};

for (const [_, key, value] of matches) {
  const numbers = value.split(",").map((n) => parseInt(n));

  product[key] = numbers;
}

const variableName = Object.keys({ test })[0]; // https://stackoverflow.com/a/52598270/8211893

prod.push({
  name: variableName,
  product
});

console.log(prod);



am ignoring the pipe character. Also I am only checking for one character before the semicolon, so you might want to adjust that expression.
