# Javascript: Reference a variable name from the variable itself

Tags: javascript

I want to create a quick function that will `console.log` a variable name and the value. I'd like the result of the function to show in the console: `foo: bar`.

My basic idea for the function looks like this:

```
function varlog(var_name)
{
    console.log(var_name + ": " + eval(var_name));
}
```

And I'd call is thusly:

```
function someRandomFunction()
{
    var foo = "bar";
    // ... some stuff happens
    varlog("foo");
}
```

This works if `foo` is global, but doesn't work in the example provided. Another option that also only works globally is using `window[var_name]` instead of the scary `eval`.

I don't think what I'm asking is possible, but I figured I'd throw it out there.

I'm spending a lot of time attempting to be lazy. My current method is just `console.log('foo: ' + bar);` which works just fine. But now I just want to know if this is possible.

Some other questions I referenced in searching for this / creating what I have now:

- [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)
- [How to convert variable name to string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417645/how-to-convert-variable-name-to-string-in-javascript)
- [Javascript, refer to a variable using a string containing its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664282/javascript-refer-to-a-variable-using-a-string-containing-its-name)
- [How to find JavaScript variable by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724857/how-to-find-javascript-variable-by-its-name)

--

Edit: I'd love to just call `varlog(foo)`, if the name "foo" can be derived from the variable.

Comment: this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009911/javascript-get-argument-value-and-name-of-passed-variable

Comment: @najmeddine I've pretty much duplicated that with better formatting. Doh! Thanks :)

Comment: I might just extend javascript to convert all var assignments `var foo = "bar";` to `var foo = {foo:"bar"};` (mostly kidding.) (mostly)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because the variable `foo` is not accessable to the function `varlog`!  `foo` is declared in someRandomFunction, and is never passed into `varlog`, so `varlog` has no idea what the variable foo is!  You can solve this problem by passing the variable `foo` into the function(or using some sort of closure to make `foo` in the scope of `varlog`) along with its string representation, but otherwise, I think you are out of luck.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I'm assuming, just wondering if someone has some ridiculous approach around that. Because calling `varlog("foo", foo);` would work, but doesn't really save much time over `console.log( 'foo: ' + foo );`

Comment: Right, well after looking around a little more, I think that you aren't going to be able to achieve this.  Are you just looking for some syntax sugar?

Comment: Just being lazy. It's the different of `varlog(foo);` and `console.log('foo: ' + foo);`.

Answer (score 28):

## Solution - *(for your actual use case)* - `console.log({foo})`

In **ES6** `IdentifierReference`s are being accepted as `PropertyDefinition`s on the [**`ObjectLiteral`**](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-ObjectLiteral)'s `PropertyDefinitionList` ([**see compatibility chart**](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_shorthand_properties)):

The variable **name** is being set to the `Object`'s `Property`'s **`key`**
and the variable **value** is being set to the `Object`'s `Property`'s **`value`**.

As **`console.log`** shows `Object`s with their `Propertiy`/ies' `key`s and `value`s you can use that to see both your variable's *name* and *value* by invoking **`console.log({foo})`**.

> Note that when you initialize a single anonymous `object` with several
>   variables as I did in the second `console.log` while they appear in
>   the same order as initialized here in the snippet's output they might
>   get reordered (alphabetically) elsewhere.

```js
var testint = 3
var teststring = "hi"
var testarr = ["one", 2, (function three(){})]
var testobj = {4:"four", 5:"five", nested:{6:"six",7:"seven"}}
console.log({testint})
console.log({testint, teststring, testarr, testobj})
```

## Answer - *(to the question title)* - `Object.keys({foo})[0]`

You can also use this shorthand `Object Initializer` together with `Object.keys()` to straightly access the variable name:

```js
var name = "value"
console.log(Object.keys({name})[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yet this is not working when I try to use `console.log({this})`?

Comment: `this` is not a variable name, it is a reserved keyword :)

Answer (score 4):

While I'm not aware of such a possibility, I'd wanted to share a small idea:

```
Object.prototype.log = function(with_message) {
  console.log(with_message + ":" + this);
}

var x = "string";
x.log("x");
```

Like I said, a small idea.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of combining a couple of anwers into a small function

Would this work for you?

```
const log = function() {
  const key = Object.keys(this)[0];
  const value = this[key];
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

let someValue = 2;

log.call({someVlaue}); //someValue: 2
```

Works with function too, even itself.

```
log.call({log});

// It would return the following
log:function() {
  const key = Object.keys(this)[0];
  const value = this[key];
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just define it as `function(obj) {...}` and then use `obj` instead of `this`, and then call it with normal function call syntax, i.e. `log({foo})`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe what you want to do is possible.

The best alternative I can think of is to pass an object to `varlog` that is basically a key-value hash:

```
function varlog(obj)
{
    for (var varname in obj) {
        console.log(varname + ": " + obj[varname]);
    }
}


function someRandomFunction()
{
    var foo = "bar";
    // ... some stuff happens
    varlog({foo: foo});
}
```

Comment: That totally works, thought doesn't have the time saving benefits of just passing the variable name once. Similar to just calling `varlog("foo",foo);`. But, it does work! :)

Answer (score 0):

I loved @mhitza idea, so I'm making it a little bigger...

The downside is the need to use `.value`to reach the variable content.

```js
Object.prototype.log = function(message) {
  if (message) console.log(this.name, this.value, message);
  else console.log(this.name, this.value);
}

function nar (name, value) {
  var o = {name: name, value: value};
  this[name] = o;
  return o;
}

// var globalVar = 1;
nar('globalVar', 1); 

globalVar.log();
// > globalVar 1

globalVar.value += 5;

globalVar.log('equal six');
// > globalVar 6 equal six

var someFunction = function () {
  // var localVar = 2;
  nar('localVar', 2);

  localVar.log('someInfo');
  // > localVar 2 someInfo
};

someFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprised to see no super simple solution yet.

```
let varname = "banana"
console.log(`${JSON.stringify({varname}).split('"')[1]}`)
```

Prints `varname` in the console