# How to get variable keyword instead of variable value

Tags: javascript, variables, printing

I'm created a function to print a object or an array, this print the properties name and values ok, but I can't figure out how can I print the "testobject" intead of "object" on the first line of the output.

part of the function

```
function expandNode(obj) {
    for (var node in obj) {
        text += node + " => " + obj[node] + "<br>";  //keyword => value
    }
    return (text);
}
```

exemple

```
var testobject={};
testobject["car"]="toyota";
testobject["instrument"]="piano";
testobject["computer"]="macintosh";
document.write( printO(testobject) );
```

the output is

```
object
(
    car => toyota
    instrument => piano
    computer => macintosh
)
```

Comment: Fyi, you should never use `new Array()` but `[]` instead. Additionally, using `document.write()` is bad as it will erase everything in your document if you use it after the DOM is fully loaded. Additionally you need to make `myarray` an object, using `{}` instead of `new Array()`, since arrays only have keys in the interval `[0, length)`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I know... I was just testing the function on a empty DOM. actually the function is able to print both [] and {}

Comment: @ThiefMaster I simplified the question, removing the whole function and only kept a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. The only thing you can do is passing the variable name, too:

```
printO('someVar', someVar);
```

No need to say that this is extremely ugly so better don't do it at all.

---

Since another answer suggested to pass only the name and use `eval` to access the value:
This would work for globals - but in that case the better way would be not using eval but the `[]` operator on the global object (`window` or `this`). Since it's impossible to access a value from a local scope though there is no good way to make your function accept only the variable name.

Comment: I thought it, but I think I will only print the "parent" type, `object(` or `array(`. it will be more elegant solution, I guess... but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Unfortunately this isn't possible in Javascript. The best you could do would be to pass in the variable name as a string and then use `eval()` to access the actual variable:</strike>

```
function printO(obj_str) {
  alert("The variable name is " + obj_str);
   obj = eval(obj_str);
}
```

See also this question:
[How to convert variable name to string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417645/how-to-convert-variable-name-to-string-in-javascript)

Edit: In fact, the above solution won't work; see discussion below.

Comment: Eval is evil and it would only work with global variables. And then it wouldn't be necessary at all since he could use `this[obj_str]` or `window[obj_str]` to access it. But there'd be absolutely no way to access a variable from a local context.

Comment: I don't disagree that `eval` is evil, but I thought, as `eval` runs in the same scope as the caller, it would still work. But I'm guessing I'm mistaken.

Comment: I'm using the same methodology to open children, but I can't get the variable name outside a parent. But I can't get the point of your code.

Comment: Yes, `eval` does run in the scope of the caller - and the caller is `printO`, so unless you actually define the *function* `printO` in the context where the variable you want to access is available it won't work.