# explanation converting variable name to string

Tags: javascript

> Some people beieved that this is a duplicate of [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript), this is incorrect. If you read the test below, you would understand that the methods provided were not satisfactory since this variable **HAS** to be a variable, it cannot be an object property.

I have been looking around for "How to convert variable name to string", but all I got was(as explained in [How to convert variable name to string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417645/how-to-convert-variable-name-to-string-in-javascript)) objects and things that only worked in the global scope.

Is there a way to convert a variable name DIRECTLY into a string, without doing weird stuff.

like:

```
var alertThis = "dont alert this"
alert(alertThis.forVarToString());
// This should return "alertThis"
```

This functionality is quite necessary for what I am doing.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? I'm pretty sure it's not necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable name as a string in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @JCOC611 This is no duplicate because as I said, the answers given dont help with what I'm trying to accomplish(sense I can't make my variable an object property)

Comment: Well those are the *only* ways to accomplish it (either transverse the window object and try to find your variable, assuming you drop the `var`, or you use an object instead). Otherwise, you could try sharing the *why* of this question so we can help more.

Comment: This is still an XY problem.   In almost every possible scenario, if you are trying to call `alertThis` and have it output a string, you already would need to know that variable's name in order to write the code for it, and `'alertThis'` would be obvious.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97358/discussion-on-question-by-julian-avar-explanation-converting-variable-name-to-st).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's generally possible (it's an internal value stored in some symbol table). Global variables are of course exposed on `this` (e.g. window), so you can determine whether a given string is a global identifier:

```
var hello = 'Hi';
Object.keys(window).indexOf('hello') >= 0;
//=> true
```

As regards the *method* for converting any identifier to its string representation (not what it's referring to), that wouldn't be very useful, because to *call* that method, you would have to first *have* that identifier, in which case you would already know its name.

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking too much, but what does `.indexOf('hello') >= 0;` do?

Comment: @julianavar `Object.keys(window)` is a list of strings, so `indexOf('hello')` returns the index of `'hello'` in that list if it's found. Otherwise returns `-1`. So by checking for `>= 0`, we're checking if `window.hello` is declared.

Comment: Yeah, that wont do...

Comment: And by the way, this feature is quite useful for what I am trying to do, it might not seem useful to you, but that is only because maybe you haven't seen a need to do this yet. I have and that is why I ask.

Comment: @julianavar JCOC611 made a *key* suggestion: preprocess your code instead. I suspect that's what you're trying to do, except you're letting the js engine do the processing for you and then you ask it for values. Instead, parse your code, make a list of identifiers and then do stuff with them before handing the code off to the interpreter?

Comment: But how would I do that? I'm sorry if I'm not an expert in this topic, but what are you talking about? What is a preprocessing and how would it work. How would I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @julianavar To preprocess, you'd simply parse the code and store what follows `var` in some table called 'identifiers'. Then you hand the code intact to the compiler, which does its thing with it. One way of accomplishing this goal is to use a javascript parser (e.g. *Esprima*) and let it generate an abstract syntax tree, from which you can then easily extract the identifiers (the tree will likely be in json format).

Comment: Or, you know, explain _why_ you need to do this and perhaps we can suggest an alternative other than preprocessing your JS.

Comment: @Andy ok, but If i do post my question, you have to understand that it is a very specific situation

Comment: Just add the relevant details to your question, or delete this one and ask another. You've got a lot of pushback here because it looks like like an XY problem: ["That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: @Andy ok, but then you do understand that the question I would write would be quite long a detailed. I am trying to do a TON of stuff, and I was pretty sure that I could get the answer here, if you think that you can take an extremelly long explanation(which is all necesarry in order to correctly address the problems), then tell me and I will post a new qeustion. I just want to make sure that the question I will make will be addressed and will not just be ignored(which happens a lot in specific code).

Comment: I can't tell you it will be addressed. Would the response be worse than the one you've got for this question? Probably not.

Comment: @Andy ok, then I will post my new question as soon as finished. :) Thank you for your support!

Comment: It has taken over an hour and I HAVENT gotten anywhere, the question ends up being to long. I'll just have to leave it as it is...