# Get the variable name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have an object called **main** and its one of the item, **data:** ,  points to an array defined as **submenuitem**. When user clicks on something, the UI gets updated with array items in **submenuitems**. It also updates the topbar to display the title of current menu which is basically the variable name **SUBMENUITEMS**.

Can anyone tell how can I get the submenu item variable name **data: "--->this<--"** as String?

```
let submenuItems = ["subMenu 1","subMenu 2","subMenu 3","subMenu 4","subMenu 5","subMenu 6"];

let main = {
    title:'main menu', 
    menuLogo:'img/logo1.png',
    data:submenuItems
}
```

**Edit:**

I see a lot of confusion. Actually this a part of my code which is written using Vuejs -

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in dataArray" v-on:click="subMenu(item)" v-bind:id="'tile_'+index" class="card">
                <div><img v-bind:src=item.menuLogo onerror="this.src='img/default.svg'" /></div>
                <div>{{item.title}}</div> 
                <div>{{index+1}}</div>
            </div>



let subhome = [ 
{"title":"sub_card_title","sub_cardimage":"sub_item1.png",data:[]},
{"title":"sub_card_title","sub_cardimage":"sub_item1.png",data:[]},    {"title":"sub_card_title","sub_cardimage":"sub_item1.png",data:[]},`
{"title":"sub_card_title","sub_cardimage":"sub_item1.png",data:[]}
] 

let home = [ 
{"title":"card_title","cardimage":"item1.png",data:[]},
{"title":"card_title","cardimage":"item1.png",data:subhome},    {"title":"card_title","cardimage":"item1.png",data:[]},`
{"title":"card_title","cardimage":"item1.png",data:[]}
] 



 let menu = new Vue({
        el: '#menu',
        data: {
            dataArray: home
        },
        methods: {
            subMenu: function(item) {
                if (item.data.length > 0) {
                    this.dataArray = item.data;
                    console.log('sub menu array -->', this.dataArray);
                    $('#menu-title').text(eval(item));
                }
            },setTitle: function(val) {
                 let title = eval(val); // <---- how to vaiable name of data array
                 $('#spancontainer').text(title)
            }  
        } 
    });
```

Comment: You want data to be `subMenu 1, subMenu 2 ....`

Comment: `"submenuItems"` ?

Comment: wouldn't you need to pass it as an object - something like `data: { 'submenuItems': submenuItems 
 }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert variable name to string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417645/how-to-convert-variable-name-to-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal No, I don't want values. I want the "subemnuitems" as string.

Comment: @JonasW.yes, I want that as string. Thank you, only you understood my question.

Comment: @melpomene No, I know that already and it doesn't solve my problem.Please see my edit.

Comment: @Greyfrog You didn't make an edit.

Comment: @melpomene I am sorry I was editing. please check now

Comment: I don't understand your new code (or what it has to do with the question), but I'm pretty sure using `eval()` is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
let submenuItems = ["subMenu 1","subMenu 2","subMenu 3","subMenu 4","subMenu 5","subMenu 6"];

let main = {
    title:'main menu', 
    menuLogo:'img/logo1.png',
    data:submenuItems
}
```

it is equating to

```
let main = {
    title:'main menu', 
    menuLogo:'img/logo1.png',
    data:["subMenu 1","subMenu 2","subMenu 3","subMenu 4","subMenu 5","subMenu 6"]
}
```

In order to get `"submenuItems"`, you'd need to pass it as an object and get its key like this

```
let main = {
    title:'main menu', 
    menuLogo:'img/logo1.png',
    data:{
        submenuItems: submenuItems
    }
}
console.log(Object.keys(main.data)[0]);
```

or simply create a new property and set it to `"submenuItems"` like this

```
let main = {
    title:'main menu', 
    menuLogo:'img/logo1.png',
    data:{
        name: 'submenuItems',
        submenuItems: submenuItems
    }
}
console.log(main.data.name);
```

Comment: "*If you were to update `submenuItems`, `main.data` would not reflect the changes.*" This is only true for assignments to the `submenuItems` variable itself, as in `submenuItems = ...`. Any update of the array would be reflected.

Comment: Your "proof" shows an assignment to `submenuItems`, which is what I said is the only kind of update that would not be reflected. Try `submenuItems[0] = "hi"` or `submenuItems.splice(1, 2)` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, you're right. I'll edit my answer.